# How to force black borders for UIPopoverControllers

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

`UIPopoverController` instances can be restyled in iOS5 using the `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class. However this customisation technique cannot be applied to `UIActionSheets` (presented as popovers in iPad). I'd like my popovers to appear consistent so `UIPopoverBackgroundView` isn't an option for me.

Poking through the iOS artwork (using [extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor)) I notice that alongside the `_UIPopoverViewBlue*` PNGs (presumably used to draw the default blue-ish `UIPopoverController` borders) is a `_UIPopoverViewBlack*` set of PNGs. How do I get `UIPopoverController` to use the black images instead of the blue ones?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears there’s no way to achieve this officially. I doubt it will pass the App Store review process, but this works for me on iOS 6:

```
[popoverController setValue:@3 forKey:@"_popoverBackgroundStyle"];
```

It’s a shame Apple didn’t just expose this publicly.

Comment: This works nicely! Has anyone submitted an app for review that uses this? I know Apple automatically catches undocumented method calls, but this is the first I've seen an "undocumented key" used before.

Comment: I have submit app by using this and apple have accept and my app is live now.